# Getting following Error in Sphinx 4.0- 'helloLinguist' property:'grammar' - mandatory property is not set

Tags: cmusphinx, sphinx4

I am using sphinx 4.0 recognizer.While am  running my application for swapping two statically defined grammars at runtime, i am getting the error in ecllipse as " 'helloLinguist' property:'grammar' - mandatory property is not set! ". I am using the  cofiguration xml file provided on the link http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/sphinx4:swappinggrammars. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You must have accidentally edited the configuration and removed/commented the entry, or you are removing the `grammar` element during runtime. In the configuration you linked the property is set:

```
<component name="helloLinguist" 
            type="edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist">
    <property name="grammar" value="helloGrammar"/>
</component>
```